# How do I control in SHINY that the HTML background does not show when no output is available

Tags: html, r, shiny

After clicking Submit, the output content is correct, but there is a gray background box before the output. If I delete the height in the HTML, there will still be two small arrows, which looks ugly.
The tag $style is mainly for scrolling through Fasta text, but after that I can't make it disappear without any output, which really bothers me. Please help me, thank you.

**Before submit**
[image: Before submit]

**Click submit**
[image: Click submit]

```r
fluidRow(
    column(4, downloadButton("sequence.txt", "Download Sequence", style = "width:100%;", class = "buttDown")),
    column(4,downloadButton("genesequence.txt", "Download Gene Sequence", style = "width:100%;", class = "buttDown")),
    column(4,downloadButton("genesinfo.txt", "Download Gene Information", style = "width:100%;", class = "buttDown"))
),
          
textOutput("seq_title"),
verbatimTextOutput("seq"),
tags$head(tags$style("#seq_title{color: red;
                              font-size: 22px;
                              font-style: bold;
                            }"
),
tags$style("#seq{
            width = 100%;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
          height: 300px;
}")
),
textOutput("cds_title"),
verbatimTextOutput("cds"),
tags$head(tags$style("#cds_title{color: red;
                              font-size: 22px;
                              font-style: bold;
                            }"
),
tags$style("#cds{
            width = 100%;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
}")
),
textOutput("pro_title"),
shiny::verbatimTextOutput("pro"),
tags$head(tags$style("#pro_title{color: red;
                              font-size: 22px;
                              font-style: bold;
                            }"
),
tags$style("#pro{
            width = 100%;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            display:block;
            
}")
),
DT::dataTableOutput("geneinfo"),

textOutput("genetitle"),
verbatimTextOutput("searchgenesequence"),
tags$head(tags$style("#genetitle{color: red;
                              font-size: 22px;
                              font-style: bold;
                            }"
),
tags$style("#searchgenesequence{
            width = 100%;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
}")
)
```

Comment: if you right click the box you will see the hex code you need to change

Comment: Can you share your complete app code to make this example reproducible?